# How to get "Additional CSS Class" for ACF Gutenberg block

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, block-editor

I have registered a custom block with ACFs `acf_register_block`. I have set a `render_callback` to load a php template but would like to access any extra CSS classes which the user may have set in the admin.

[image]

Does WordPress provide a global like `$block` (similar to `$post`) or would I need to raise a question on the ACF support forums?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Note that I don't have ACF PRO 5.8 which comes with the Block features, but I hope this answer helps.*

If you look at the example [here](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/block-api/block-edit-save/#saving-attributes-to-child-elements), you can retrieve the additional/custom CSS classes using `props.attributes.className`; i.e. the classes are saved as an *attribute* named `className`.

So with that in mind and based on [`acf_register_block()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_register_block) (which as of writing, it redirects to [`acf_register_block_type()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_register_block_type/)), your `render_callback` function would receive a `$block` array (the block settings and attributes) as the first argument, and therefore you should be able to retrieve the additional CSS class(es) via `$block['className']` as shown [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_register_block_type/#examples) — see the example under "*Registering a block with callback*".

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I don't know why I didn't just try a `var_dump($block)` as I said in my own question!

Comment: I don't know, either.. :) But anyway, I'm glad I could help.